# My vs code python path has 2 different paths showing? one in white and one in blue

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, path

I am realizing the hardest part in learning to code is knowing how to even ask the right questions.. 
ill try and word it as best i can. I also will attach a screenshot.

I am running code in the terminal through VS code... and there is just so many files being shown every time i run the code. There is white and blue text that seems like the same thing? It makes it hard for me to see whats going on. Is there anyway to shorten or completely remove it? it seems 100% useless for just running some basic code.

[image: Description]

Comment: Not sure what kind of answer you expect here. Your path is long because you saved your file at that location...

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen why are there 2 paths though? one in white and one in blue?

Comment: the white one is the prompt and the the blue one is the full path of the py file. One tip **don't** use spaces in file/directory names

Comment: @rioV8 thank you. Do you know how i can get rid of the full path and only use the prompt? or is that not a thing

Comment: Why do you have 3 subdirectories that all mean `Exercise`? Now the Python plugin knows for sure the debugger is running the correct py file. In the `launch.json` the CWD might be set different.

Answer (score 0):

The

> C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/shared/python37_64/python.exe

Is the Absolute path of the python executable.
And the

> C:/PythonProjects/vscode/...../helloworld_start.py

Is the absolute path of the file that you are running.
Simple it is running

```
python helloworld_start.py
```

If you want to reduce this. You can simply open a terminal and change the directory to the current working directory and simply run the above command. This will use the relative path to run the helloworld_start.py file

First you need to add python to the Environment variables and then Open the terminal uin VSCode using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> and then `cd` to the current working directory and run `python helloworld_test.py`

Comment: sorry i dont understand. I tried changing my CWD in my debugger because thats all that shows me what to do when i google your directions.

Comment: I have added more info . Please check it. [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Rx_JRkwAjY)

Comment: how do i remove the python executable path? i dont want both paths showing. it wasnt like this before, i dont understand what changed.

Comment: I want you to run the program using terminal manually. Not by using VSCode.